# Online Based Apache Web Log Analyzer By Submitting Just the Raw Logfile

Tags: apache, open-source

I have a raw "access.log" file from Apache. Is there any web based version tool where I can just submit this raw log file and return me the analysis results

I am aware of the code such as [AWSTATS](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), but it require us to install it in the server, which is not what I want.

Comment: just a bit concerned about security policies, you should maybe anonymize those log before submitting to an stat provider.

Also take a look into google analytics maybe better for you then apache log based solution.

Comment: @RageZ: Thanks for the suggestion. BTW googleanalytics can only give stats starting from the registration date and not past.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Instead of uploading the `access.log` file to an unknown and untrusted third party, I'd suggest installing a desktop application like [Apache Log Viewer](http://www.apacheviewer.com/). Quoted from its website:

> Apache Logs Viewer (ALV) is a free and powerful tool which lets you **monitor**, **view** and **analyze** apache logs with more ease. It offers **search** and **filter** functionality for the log file, highlighting the various http requests based on their status code. There is also a report facility, thus you can generate a pie/bar chart in seconds. Together with this there are also statistics where you can get the top hits, top errors, number of status codes, total bandwidth and more.
>
> Apache Logs Viewer is a great tool to use for web analytics. Use it to get your website more productive, detect any errors and fix them. You can determine the visitors originating country and if the referrer logging is enabled than it is easier to see from which website the clients are coming from, the search terms used and which pages where visited.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Easy installation (Windows Application)
> - Does not require installing on Apache Server
> - Color code Log lines according to status codes
> - Translate IP to Country using GeoLite Database (fast with no lookups)
> - Search for IP Address, Request String, Date, Referrer
> - Filter according to HTTP Status Code (or Range)
> - Export to text file/comma separated value, txt/csv
> - Visual Reports (Pie/Bar Charts)
> - Statistics

Comment: Looks nice, but no versions for Mac & Linux :(

Comment: Little update: by Jan 2013, the app is no longer free will all features. It requires a donation before you can unlock features like filtering by date. Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: AVL free version has limited functionality

Comment: Also, all the reporting is a paid feature. 15 Euros so far.

Comment: Shame they don't have a fully working option for testing... 
You have no idea what you are paying for.

Answer (score 16):

If you like the command line style and are *nix based http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/ ticks the box for me, available via brew as well for mac for nice and easy installation, but dont expect pretty graphs...

Comment: The Homebrew version is pretty outdated, but you can follow the Ubuntu instructions inside a Docker container for good results.

Answer (score 7):

I tried 'Apache Log Viewer' (it sounds like an Apache product, but I don't think it is) and it seems to be complete rubbish.  The pie charts for country are useless and unsorted - .0023% Tobago or something.  I could find no way to get figures for single html pages. The colour coding only shows e.g.304 in red or something. There seems to be no recognition of e.g. google and other spiders.  AWStats despite its limiatations appears to be much better.

The general appearance is like very mnay bits of software: a row of buttons with hardly any indication of what they do, the usual 'File' Edit' things with, again, single words which you have to try to decode, unhelpful help and all the rest.

I doubt it's worth wasting time on it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on a mac (or *nix, windows) you can check out http://www.sawmill.net which has a standalone app that does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try that [Online tools](http://sharontools.com/tools/LogAnalysis/Main.php)

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [Nihuo Web Log Analyzer](http://www.loganalyzer.net). Easy to use, powerful filter system can help you mining out each detail information from your log files.