# ApacheTop for Windows

Tags: windows, apache, logging, monitoring

I'm running Apache on Windows 7 x64.

I'd like to find a tool to analyze Apache **access log** and to monitor server loads.

Is there a good analyzing / monitoring tool for Apache on windows 7?

Preferably with GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Apache log viewer: http://www.apacheviewer.com/
  Download is free but this version is very very limited. You (nearly) can't create a report without 10$ donation and unlock code.
- Weblog expert: http://www.weblogexpert.com/
  Full version is very rich featured for 30 days trial, Lite version is free
- Deep log analyzer: http://www.deep-software.com/
  Full version 25 days trial, Free version is with less tools
- Web Log Suite: http://www.exacttrend.com/weblogsuite/
  No free version

Also similar: [Online Based Apache Web Log Analyzer By Submitting Just the Raw Logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475827/online-based-apache-web-log-analyzer-by-submitting-just-the-raw-logfile)

Some links: http://softwaresolution.informer.com/Web-Statistics-Report/